# QML Qt Images not in .exe file

Tags: image, qt, qml

if have the following problem:
I load QML files with an QQmlApplicationEngine like:

```
m_qappenginePresentationOnSmallCircleSegment.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("PresentationOnSmallCircleSegment.qml").absoluteFilePath()));
```

In my QML I load an Image like this:

```
valPic = "qrc:/images/ExternalRessources/MyImage.png";
```

My Folder struture is like this:
[image: Folder structure of QML and .png files]

==> When I am building and debugging my app, every picture inside the QML is perfect. However, if I start my .exe out of my debug folder, it works but NO .png image shows up... I tried now for hours and did not to get it work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _If I start my .exe out of my debug folder_  did you deploy your project correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with qrc, or the images being in the exe file. You're using a dynamically linked version of Qt, and when you run it, it doesn't find the image format plugins.